# How to Fetch Woo Commerce Product Categories icons with names with get_term(product_cat) or something else .. can i fetch only name?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

```
<?php 
$orderby = 'id';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false ;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty'=> 0,
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '
<ul class="display-categories list-group nav navbar-nav">';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '
<li class="list-group-item">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo '<img src="'.get_term_link($category).'" />' ;
        echo $category->name;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}          
?>
```

I can't fetch the product category icons.. i want it to fetch category icons with the list of names ... please somebody help me out with this thanks

Answer (score 0):

Category Icons / Images has been stored in terms meta and can be retrieved by using

```
$term_meta = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $category_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$category_icon = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_meta );
```